# Vb.Net something that i want to fix in my function - Stopwatch

Tags: vb.net, stopwatch

i make function that convert time string ("hh\:mm\:ss\,fff" - example:"00:00:00,100") to parts

strTime = "00:00:00,100" = 
**h** int = 0
**m** int = 0
**sec** int = 0
**millisec** int = 100


The function:

```
Public Function ShowInLabel(ByVal TEXT As String, ByVal time As String, ByVal startTime As Boolean) As Boolean
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim sss As String
        sss = time
        Dim start As String = StrReverse(sss)
        start = StrReverse(start.Substring(0, 3))
        Dim s As Integer
        s = Integer.Parse(start)
        Dim secstart As String = StrReverse(sss).Substring(0, 6)
        secstart = StrReverse(secstart)
        Dim secs As Integer = Integer.Parse(secstart.Substring(0, 2))
        Dim hurs As Integer = Integer.Parse(sss.Substring(0, 2))
        Dim mins As Integer = Integer.Parse(StrReverse(StrReverse(sss.Substring(0, 5)).Substring(0, 2)))

        Dim stopWatch As New Stopwatch()
        stopWatch.Start()
noh:
        If stopWatch.Elapsed.Hours = hurs Then
            GoTo yesh
        Else
            GoTo noh
        End If
yesh:
        If stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes = mins Then
            GoTo yesm
        Else
            GoTo yesh
        End If
yesm:
        If stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds = secs Then
            GoTo yess
        Else
            GoTo yesm
        End If
yess:

        If stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds > s Or stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds = s Then
            GoTo done
        Else
            GoTo yess
        End If
done:
        If startTime = False Then
            Label1.Text = ""
        Else
            Label1.Text = TEXT
        End If

        Return True

    End Function
```

example:

```
ShowInLabel("SubTitle", "00:00:00,100", True)
```

The Function Works ,

but when the function runing the application is Stucked **Till** the function return true
Why it happening?

Comment: Am I seeing `GOTO` statements?

Comment: What can replace this statements?

Comment: Would this happen to be Windows Form development? In that case the Timer class could be of some help. It has the Tick event that will solve both the hanging thread problem, and help discard the goto's.

Comment: @LarsTech, if you look carefully you will see also `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Maybe someone can give me example that Describes the Solution?

Comment: @NikoMman, sorry, I really don't wish to be sarcastic or rude in my comment. You have all the rights to ask, but an old hand, like me, frowns every time I see again that kind of code. Too many bugs and headhaches from GOTO, ON ERROR RESUME NEXT, global vars etc.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is something like this:

```
    Dim time As Date = DateTime.ParseExact("00:01:02,123", "hh:mm:ss,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim h As Integer = time.Hour
    Dim m As Integer = time.Minute
    Dim sec As Integer = time.Second
    Dim millisec As Integer = time.Millisecond
```

However, being all to familiar with what you're trying to accomplish :), I suspect what you really need is this:

```
    Dim time As Date = DateTime.ParseExact("00:01:02,123", "hh:mm:ss,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim startTime As Date = DateTime.ParseExact("00:00:00,000", "hh:mm:ss,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim elapsed As TimeSpan = time - startTime
    Dim totalMilliseconds As Integer = CType(elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, Integer)
```

You could, in the same way, convert the start and end times for each subtitle to total milliseconds and then compare them that way.

As others have pointed out, On Error Resume Next is only really available in VB.NET for backwards compatibility with VB6 code.  You should use a Try/Catch block, instead.  However, just putting a resume next above your entire method was never considered good practice, even in VB6, just as putting a try/catch block around the entire method would also be considered a bad idea.

Similarly, GoTo is just about the most terrible thing you could ever do by just about any programmer's sensibilities.  You should consider other options such as loops, if/else blocks, breaking the code up into separate methods, etc., and avoid GoTo's at all costs.

Comment: Tnx Bro! in this why easier to extract evreything :), but the "goto" thing still annoying :/

Comment: Thanks for trying to be more specific in your question.  You're improving!

Comment: i tryied Do While stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds <> secs Application.Doevents() Loop -- and timers, and it Still not works bro

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  Does it get stuck in the loop?  You shouldn't be doing that.  DoEvents is a bad idea, whenever possible it should be avoided.  You should, instead, use a quick timer as I suggested in your previous question.

Comment: Yes , it stucked in the loop Although Seconds  = secs

Comment: i will try timer again( Maybe because that the strings and the Stopwatch is not Public(evreything get Reset)

Comment: Try to divide your logic into simple methods that serve a single purpose.  For instance, I'd suggest making a method like `Function GetSubTitle(elapsedMilliseconds As Integer) As SubTitle`.  Then in the timer, just call that.  Have it return Nothing if there is no valid subtitle for that particular millisecond.